# Two way bind into template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, two-way-binding

I've been searching for hours now and i just can't figure it out..
Is there any way that i could bind the data from an input, send it to the template and here use the data?

Let me paint the picture...

> *edit.php*

```
<form>
  <input v-model="?">
</form>

<prod-preview name="somehowsendthename"></prod-preview>
```

> *prod-preview.vue*

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "product-preview",
    props: ["name"],
    data(){
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    },
}
```

Don't worry about binding the actual component, that works. Thank you

Comment: Use :name="name" on your child component, put name as data in your parent component, and remove name data from your child. Then v-model="name" on your input

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
// edit.vue
<template>
    <form>
      <input v-model="name">
    </form>
    <prod-preview :name="name"></prod-preview>
</template>
<script>
import ProdPreview from './prod-preview'
export default {
    name: "edit",
    components: [ProdPreview],
    data(){
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    },
}
</script>

// prod-preview.vue
<template>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "product-preview",
    props: ["name"]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a name in from the blade and bind it to the data in the view component, you want a prop with a different name, something like `initialName` and then set the data name that you bind with v-model using the initialName like this...

```
export default {
  name: "product-preview",
  props: ["initialName"],
  data(){
      return {
          name: this.initialName
      }
  },
}
```

Note that html attributes are case insensitive so you'd pass that in like this and it will be received by the correct prop:

```
<prod-preview initial-name="{{ $name }}"></prod-preview>
```

You can now v-bind to "name" and it will keep the data attribute name current as you change that input and you won't be attempting to change a prop which should not be done.

Comment: if you're unclear about where that {{ $name }} var gets set, show me your return line in you controller method and I'll help with that.

Comment: That's exactly what is unclear to me, what should i pass in?

Comment: Did you intend to have your form with the v-model outside of your vue template?  I think if you use a component with it's own template you cannot also bind it to the html in your blade file.

Comment: In my example above, the name variable would have been set in the controller on the backend but if you intended to have the html in your blade file bound to a vue component and another vue component inside if it, you're going to need to define two vue objects like @CUGreen showed in his answer.

Comment: yes, i guess that is my issue, it just cant be done, well you pointed me to the right direction anyway so thank you :)